# How to execute ajax query immediately and periodically in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In Rails 4 I have index and show views for a class (zones) that have fairly complex javascript to update values.  For DRYness, the HTML just creates a data-less layout and the js file inserts the data, modifies the style, and so on.  This data needs to be updated every 15 seconds or so.  A `common.js.coffee` file contains

```
root = exports ? this
root.executeQuery = (isAsync = true) ->
  if $('#ajaxParams')? and $('#ajaxParams').data('model')?
  # Use dynamic updates
  update_url = '/' + $('#ajaxParams').data('model')
  if $('#ajaxParams').data('id')?
    update_url += '/' + $('#ajaxParams').data('id')
  update_url += '.js'
  $.ajax({url: update_url, async: isAsync, dataType: "script"}).done (content) ->
    setTimeout ( ->
      executeQuery()
    ), 15000
else
  setTimeout ( ->
    executeQuery()
  ), 15000
```

which handles the periodic update.  Then `zones.js.coffee` contains

```
$(document).ready ->
  executeQuery(false)
```

So on page ready, the query is run, the dynamic content is inserted, the timer is scheduled and then updates periodically.  So far, so good, But when I click on a a link that takes me to the zones show method, the page is data-less until the timer kicks off the ajax request.  There is no page ready event.  The same thing happens when I click on a show link to go back to the index.

How do I get these views to always update immediately, or at least cache their previous data, and then do their periodic update?

Comment: Couldn't you put in an onclick event? `object.onclick=function(){Ajax request};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There is no page ready event. The same thing happens when I click on a show link to go back to the index
```

---

This problem will be caused by **`Turbolinks`**

Turbolinks basically keeps the `<head>` tags on your page, and loads the `<body>` via ajax. Although it offers some performance benefits, it causes all sorts of issues trying to load JS dynamically. To fix this, you'll need to: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) :

```
$(document).ready ->
  executeQuery(false)
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(executeQuery)
$(document).on('page:load', executeQuery)
```

You'll need to encapsulate your function in a variable, like this:

```
executeQuery = -> 

    (isAsync = true) ->
       if $('#ajaxParams')? and $('#ajaxParams').data('model')?
           # Use dynamic updates
           update_url = '/' + $('#ajaxParams').data('model')
       if $('#ajaxParams').data('id')?
          update_url += '/' + $('#ajaxParams').data('id')
          update_url += '.js'
          $.ajax({url: update_url, async: isAsync, dataType: "script"}).done (content) ->
             setTimeout ( ->
                 executeQuery()
             ), 15000
      else
             setTimeout ( ->
                 executeQuery()
             ), 15000
```

I think you'll have to rename your function name (I could not glean the exact context from your question only), as you seem to be [self-referencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference)

Comment: That solved my problem entirely.  Thank you!  I got rid of the parameter and the else clause because that was just my hack to try and solve the problem.  I'm not quite sure what your concern was with the self-reference.  That's just the function rescheduling itself.